# x86 Assembly Reference Sheet

Tags: assembly

In my latest quest to learn some assembly language I'm finding myself constantly going to the web to find the definitions or descriptions for a particular register or mnemonic, ect.

I'm looking for a handy Reference Sheet that I can print up and refer to every time I see a symbol and I "can't quite remember" what it was.

Has anyone come across something like this on the web for themselves?

Comment: Hundred of runnable asserts on mine: https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-assembly-cheat :-)

Comment: - [x64_cheatsheet.pdf](https://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs033/docs/guides/x64_cheatsheet.pdf)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This [site](http://ref.x86asm.net/) seems useful.

Comment: You can also [search this site using Google Search](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=active&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=site:http%3A%2F%2Fref.x86asm.net%2F&oq=site:http%3A%2F%2Fref.x86asm.net%2F&gs_l=hp.3...1440.1440.0.1959.1.1.0.0.0.0.45.45.1.1.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.4.psy-ab.k1_TCupXa0k&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42661473,d.dmQ&fp=50b26647ad5972f8&biw=978&bih=602), and it returns a lot of useful search results. :)

Answer (score 18):

There's one available [here](http://www.jegerlehner.com/intel/), it's linked from wikipedia as well

Comment: Thank you, this is the nuts! (It's a beautiful cheat-sheet on two sides of A4).

Answer (score 4):

I usually use [Wikipedia's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings)

Answer (score 4):

The one Jeff linked is good, but it's covering 80186 too, which I think bloats it a bit.

For GNU as on i386 I recommend this one: **[gcc x86 Assembly Quick Reference ("Cheat Sheet")](http://www.cs.uaf.edu/2005/fall/cs301/support/x86/index.html)**

Remember the length suffixes, [covered here](https://github.com/yasm/yasm/wiki/GasSyntax#Integer_Suffixes)! The other one uses wide registers but doesn't use long operands.