# TASM - Registers?

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

I'm pretty much confused how registers work in TASM or Assembly. Especially when assigning an integer value inside it. I can't really find a clear tutorial out there.

Can somebody please explain to me the use of these registers:

```
AX, BX, CX, DX,

AH AL, BL BH, CL CH, DL DH
```

I saw a program that uses CX for loop counters. Can I also use it as a host for a certain integer value at the same time?

I have so many questions in mind to be honest. I don't even know how to perform addition, subtration in x86

Our professor really didn't give us anything to refer with. We were not even taught how to perform mathematical operations in assembly. During lectures we are only given codes which are explained briefly (like how the code works without explaining what each lines are for). All we do during activities is copy and paste his code and modify it aimlessly.

And yeah, he gave as an assignment that is not even within our knowledge yet.

Sorry for ranting here.

Update:
I want to create a nested loop, here's a pseudo code.

```
; for (CX = 6; CX != 0; CX--) { // PSEUDO CODE, 
    ; for (BL = 0; BL != 7-CX; BL++) { 
        ; putchar(M+BL);
    ; }
    ; M--;
    ; putchar(10);
    ; putchar(13);
; }
```

I have been having troubles trying to set values in my registers since I do not know exactly how they work. Please explain to me what I did wrong.

Comment: how many topics are you going to start with this code? this makes 3

Comment: it appears you are not decrementing CL at the end of your outer loop?

Comment: I thought each loop decrements `CX` by 1? So `CL` is not equal to `CX`?

@Gunner

I really have to get this done soon, or I'll fail my subject. sorry.

Comment: `ax`, `bx`, `cx`, `dx`, `al`, `ah`, `bl`, `bh`, `cl`, `ch`, `dl`, `dh` are all general-purpose registers, with some functions specific to one register. See eg. http://www.swansontec.com/sregisters.html http://www.eecg.toronto.edu/~amza/www.mindsec.com/files/x86regs.html (within the first results of Google search: register usage x86 assembly).

Comment: you can use: "rep lodsb" or "rep stosb" as mentioned here: http://www.fermi.mn.it/linux/quarta/x86/rep.htm to auto decrement cx, but i don't believe this is done for you automatically just because you have a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not initializing BL here. you need to set it to 0 before the inner loop
`INNER:`

Here you need to add BL to DL before performing the interrupt, so that you get the character M+BL as in the pseudo code.
`MOV DL, M`
`INT 21H`

This code should be removed, since it will print the character 7-CL (which is "garbage").
`MOV DL, AL`
`INT 21H`

This happens to work in your case, but for correctness it really should be a JMP rather than a JNE. You already have a conditional exit earlier in the loop so this one should be an unconditional jump.
`JNE INNER`

Comment: It's supposed to be `BL` instead of `AL`. I guess I'm going crazy.

So I added `MOV DL, BL` and `INT 21H` right after `MOV DL, M` and `INT 21H`

Please check my updated post, I seem to get a different output, with smiley characters and hearts. But now, it's in a pyramid form which is an improvement i hope?

Comment: To quote myself: "you need to _add_ BL to DL". A `MOV` is not the same as an `ADD`.

Comment: Sorry. I must have misread. This day is just too stressful for me. 

EDIT: HOLY MOTHER OF SMOKE! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

try this link: [x86 Assembly Reference Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933801/x86-assembly-reference-sheet)

without a more specif questions, here are some basics.  sorry don't have link to tutorial, this is from memory, if you have any specific questions let me know and will update

```
; assign 100 to ax (16 bit)
mov ax, 100

; add ax to bx
add bx,ax

; add to ax, memory refereced by dx
add ax,[dx]

; add 8 bit 100 to al
add al, 100
```

ah,al,bl etc hold 8 bit values

ax,bx,cx etc hold 16 bit values

eax,ebx etc hold 32 bit values

Comment: I'm trying to create a nested loop in assembly. I tried that principle, please take a look at my program. I updated my question for you to see.

Is it possible to use Cx twice with different values?

Comment: It _is_ possible to use two nested loops with LOOP instruction, if one uses xchg cx,bx to switch the contents of cx register when exiting the inner loop. (and using bx as the outer loop counter). To answer one of your questions: no, a register can hold only one value at any time.